# OSM mapnik didn't load in MOBAC

Tags: android, osmdroid, mapnik

I want to load OpenStreetMap in my android app. For this I am using Mobile Atlas Creator(MOBAC) for creating map tiles. But when I choose OpenStreetMap mapnik, red crosses are displayed. How can I get mapnik. I tried many times.

Answer (score -1):

The default Apache HttpClient user-agent was recently banned from accessing tile.openstreetmap.org (server returns 403). As a result, the Mapnik provider is no longer serving any tiles for osmdroid.

So instead of using Mapnik, use MapQuest-OSM!

Hope this helps!